# How can I make this query: 'Find which type is sold more than other?'

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have tables like as follows:

**products**

```
-productId (primarykey)

-productCategory (foreignkey)
```

**productCategories**

```
-productCategoryId (pk)

-productCategoryName
```

**soldProducts**

```
-soldProductId (pk)

-productId (fk)
```

I am trying to make query that which category of product sold more than other.

In soldProducts table, for example if "x" product on 'soldProducts'  four times,  that means "x" product sold 4 times.

According to these, how can i make this query?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a single category that has sold the most, then this is basically a `join` and `group by`:

```
select p.productCategory, count(*)
from soldProducts sp join
     products p
     on sp.productId = p.productId
group by p.productCategory
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

This answers the question (as I interpret it), but it leaves open some issues:

- What happens when there are ties (that is, more than one category is tied for first)?  You don't specify what to do.
- If you want the category name, then you need to `join` that back in.

I also note that the data model is highly limited, with no information about the purchaser, the vendor, the date of the sale, the amount sold, or returns.  Some of these could affect the results.

Comment: Thank  you so much for your help. 

-This columns in tables are short version of my original table. I just wanted to how to write this query so gave you these informations. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Just join your tables:

```
SELECT pc.productCategoryName, COUNT(*) AS Sales
FROM solProducts sp
INNER JOIN products p ON sp.productid = p.productid
INNER JOIN productCategory pc ON p.productCategoryID = pc.productCategoryID
GROUP BY pc.productCategoryName
ORDER BY Sales DESC
```

I assume that the product category foreign key in products is actually an id that maps to the product category table.

Comment: You assumed right. This one helps me, thank you so much.